# How to compare only date part of Create Date in odoo ORM search method?

Tags: python, odoo

```
attendance_record = self.pool.get('hr.attendance').search(
    cr, uid, ['&', ('create_date', '=', workfromhome[0].create_date),
              ('employee_id', '=', workfromhome[0].emp_id.id)])
```

I want to compare only date part of `create_date` in search method.

Answer (score 1):

> @v10 Odoo Search Orm Method:

```
current_date = fields.Date('Current Date', default=date.today())


list_of_attendance= [ ] 
attendance_ids = self.env['hr.attendance'].search([])

if attendance_ids:
    for res in attendance_ids :
        attendance_create_date = res.create_date
        get_create_date = attendance_create_date.split(" ")
        if current_date == get_create_date[0]:
             list_of_attendance.append(res.id)
```

- list_of_attendance will returns  search attendance ids of create date
  which you want to compare only date part.
- you cannot directly search date wise because create_date is Datetime    Field.

Comment: Thanks. but I did it by iterating over each attendance object and getting it done using datetime.strptime method. But Thanks any way.